# ¿Cómo puedo hacer salto de linea en el header de un DataGrid en WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Este es mi `DataGrid`:

[image: DataGrid]

Quiero que las columnas `TipoDocumento`, `Empresa Contratante`, `Hora de Ingreso` y `Última modificación` queden de la siguiente manera:

[image: DataGrid bien]

El problema es que soy nuevo en WPF y no sé cómo hacerlo.
Este es el `.xaml` del `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgAtencion" Height="380" Margin="10,260,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#2196F3"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nombre" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Nombre}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Apellido" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Apellido}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tipo Documento" Width="130" Binding="{Binding TipoDoc}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Documento" Width="100" Binding="{Binding NroDoc}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nro Evaluación" Width="130" Binding="{Binding Evaluacion}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Empresa Contratante" Width="200" Binding="{Binding EnoContratante}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Hora de Ingreso" Width="130" Binding="{Binding HoraIngreso}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Última Modificación" Width="150" Binding="{Binding UltModif}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Acciones" Width="*" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La única forma que encontré de hacerlo fue por el `CodeBehind` de la ventana. En el constructor agregué estas 4 líneas y pude hacer lo que necesitaba:

```
dgAtencion.Columns[2].Header = "Tipo de\nDocumento";
dgAtencion.Columns[5].Header = "Empresa\nContratante";
dgAtencion.Columns[6].Header = "Hora de\nIngreso";
dgAtencion.Columns[7].Header = "Última\nModificación";
```

Aunque me gustaría poder hacerlo directamente desde el `.xaml` para que quede más prolijo. Pero por lo pronto esta solución cumple  con lo que necesito.

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar la etiqueta `HtmlEncode="false"` en la columna para que pueda reconocer el salto de linea, quedando asi:

```html
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Nombre <br /> con Salto " Width="100" Binding="{Binding Nombre}" HtmlEncode="false" />
```

Saludos